# Appropriate test to test for difference in mean (Likert scale)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, likert

I want to find out whether the mean of a certain variable (rating on a 5-point Likert scale) significantly differs from the midpoint of the scale, i.e. 3.
My sample size is 48.
I am wondering whether a t-test or a non-parametric equivalent is suitable to answer this question, since one variable has actual data and the other one is a "pseudo"-variable containing the number 3 for every observation.

Comment: Perhaps even more important than t-test vs Wilcoxon is why the one distribution is all $3$s.

Comment: Because "3" is the value that I want to compate my other variable to